# Entity property definitions in FormType

Tags: symfony4

Is there a way to get the Entity property definition in Formtype?

I'm asking it, because i want to integrate maxlength into my formtype, but want not define the maxlength twice ( once in Entity and once in FormType )

At the moment my definitions are

Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\length(
 *     max = 25,
 *     maxMessage = "text.zu_lang"
 * )
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $ident;
```

FormType:

```
    ->add('ident', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'ident.name',
        'help' => 'ident.help',
        'attr' => [
            'maxlength' => 25
        ]
    ])
```

Is this possible? I know, i can define Constants and call them over the $options['data_class'] in FormType, but then i have even to define the maxlength twice ( with this way only in Entity )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have validation metadata in your entity, Symfony can try to guess some validation rules and the type of the field. All you have to do is to omit the `field type` and the `maxlength` rule from your field creation:

```
    ->add('ident', null, [
        'label' => 'ident.name',
        'help' => 'ident.help'
    ])
```

This way, Symfony will look for a property called `ident` inside the entity and check its annotation to say: I found a `string` with validation rules `NotBlank` and `Length`, so I'll create a `TextType` field, that is `required` with `maxlength = 25`.

You can get more details at Symfony's documentation: [Field Type Options Guessing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#field-type-options-guessing)